# How can make the other options in a question quiz unclickable in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Just new to jquery here and I'm trying to build a question and answer using this frame work,
so, I've been trying to make in such that when one of the option is been clicked then the other options should remain unclickable instantly using a conditional statement, here is my html, css, and javascript(jquery) code, thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{

    const question = [
        {
          Question: "chair",
          optionA: "dk",
          optionB: "kd",
          optionC: "dk",
          optionD: "dkd",
          answer: "optionA"
        },
        {
            Question: "Table",
            optionA: "tabl",
            optionB: "ta",
            optionC: "t",
            optionD: "tabil",
            answer: "optionA"
        },
        {
            Question: "lord",
            optionA: "lor",
            optionB: "lo",
            optionC: "l",
            optionD: "love",
            answer: "optionA"
        },
        {
            Question: "boyy",
            optionA: "boy",
            optionB: "bo",
            optionC: "b",
            optionD: "bb",
            answer: "optionA"
          }]
    
          let questionNumber= 0;
$('#startbutton').on('click', ()=>{
        $('#startbutton').hide();
        $('.questions').show();
        $('.quest').html(question[questionNumber].Question);
        $('#optionA').html(question[questionNumber].optionA);
        $('#optionB').html(question[questionNumber].optionB);
        $('#optionC').html(question[questionNumber].optionC);
        $('#optionD').html(question[questionNumber].optionD);
    })

    $('.option').on('click', (event)=>{
        if(event.target.id === question[questionNumber].answer){
            $('.option').removeClass('wronganswer');
            $(event.target).addClass('correctanswer');
           
            
        }
        
        else{
            $('.option').removeClass('correctanswer')
            $('.option').removeClass('wronganswer')
            $(event.target).addClass('wronganswer');
            
        }
       
    })

$('.nextbutton').on('click', ()=>{
        if(questionNumber<5){
            $('.quest').html(question[questionNumber+1].Question);
            $('#optionA').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionA);
            $('#optionB').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionB);
            $('#optionC').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionC);
            $('#optionD').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionD); 
            questionNumber++;
        }
        $('.option').removeClass('wronganswer');
        $('.option').removeClass('correctanswer');
       
    })
});
```

```css
.questions {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #startbutton{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #startbutton:hover{
        color: blanchedalmond;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .option{
        border: 2px solid #997295;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        background-color: #5B63B7;
        color: #CBCCFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .quest{
        border: 2px solid #997295;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background-color:  #CBCCFF;
        color: #5B63B7;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 29px;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    .option:hover{
        color: #5B63B7;
        background-color:  #CBCCFF;
    }
    ul{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .nextbutton{
        color: #CBCCFF;
        padding: 5px;
        width: fit-content;
        margin-left: 80%;
        background-color: #997295;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nextbutton:hover{
        border: 3px solid #CBCCFF;
        color: #CBCCFF;

       
    }
    .correctanswer, .correctanswer:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .wronganswer, .wronganswer:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="startbutton">CLICK HERE TO START THE QUIZ</h1>

            <div class="questions">
            <h2 class="topic"></h2>
            <h6 class="quest"></h6>
            <p class ="option" id="optionA"></p>
            <p class ="option" id="optionB"></p>
            <p class ="option" id="optionC"></p>
            <p class ="option" id="optionD"></p>
            <p class="nextbutton">NEXT></p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a button is clicked than look if the questions has a new introduced **class** '**clicked**' if so than break and do nothing. Otherwise add this class. When going to the next question just remove this stopping 'clicked' class and you can vote on the next question.

Here the relevant lines:

```
if ($('div.questions').hasClass('clicked')) return;
$('div.questions').addClass('clicked');
...
$('div.questions').removeClass('clicked');
```

Here you can test it:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{

    const question = [
        {
          Question: "chair",
          optionA: "dk",
          optionB: "kd",
          optionC: "dk",
          optionD: "dkd",
          answer: "optionA"
        },
        {
            Question: "Table",
            optionA: "tabl",
            optionB: "ta",
            optionC: "t",
            optionD: "tabil",
            answer: "optionA"
        },
        {
            Question: "lord",
            optionA: "lor",
            optionB: "lo",
            optionC: "l",
            optionD: "love",
            answer: "optionA"
        },
        {
            Question: "boyy",
            optionA: "boy",
            optionB: "bo",
            optionC: "b",
            optionD: "bb",
            answer: "optionA"
          }]
    
          let questionNumber= 0;
$('#startbutton').on('click', ()=>{
        $('#startbutton').hide();
        $('.questions').show();
        $('.quest').html(question[questionNumber].Question);
        $('#optionA').html(question[questionNumber].optionA);
        $('#optionB').html(question[questionNumber].optionB);
        $('#optionC').html(question[questionNumber].optionC);
        $('#optionD').html(question[questionNumber].optionD);
    })

    $('.option').on('click', (event)=>{
        if ($('div.questions').hasClass('clicked')) return;
        $('div.questions').addClass('clicked');
        if(event.target.id === question[questionNumber].answer){
            $('.option').removeClass('wronganswer');
            $(event.target).addClass('correctanswer');
           
            
        }
        
        else{
            $('.option').removeClass('correctanswer')
            $('.option').removeClass('wronganswer')
            $(event.target).addClass('wronganswer');
            
        }
       
    })

$('.nextbutton').on('click', ()=>{
        $('div.questions').removeClass('clicked');
        if(questionNumber<5){
            $('.quest').html(question[questionNumber+1].Question);
            $('#optionA').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionA);
            $('#optionB').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionB);
            $('#optionC').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionC);
            $('#optionD').html(question[questionNumber+1].optionD); 
            questionNumber++;
        }
        $('.option').removeClass('wronganswer');
        $('.option').removeClass('correctanswer');
       
    })
});
```

```css
.questions {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #startbutton{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #startbutton:hover{
        color: blanchedalmond;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .option{
        border: 2px solid #997295;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        background-color: #5B63B7;
        color: #CBCCFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .quest{
        border: 2px solid #997295;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background-color:  #CBCCFF;
        color: #5B63B7;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 29px;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    .option:hover{
        color: #5B63B7;
        background-color:  #CBCCFF;
    }
    ul{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .nextbutton{
        color: #CBCCFF;
        padding: 5px;
        width: fit-content;
        margin-left: 80%;
        background-color: #997295;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nextbutton:hover{
        border: 3px solid #CBCCFF;
        color: #CBCCFF;

       
    }
    .correctanswer, .correctanswer:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .wronganswer, .wronganswer:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="startbutton">CLICK HERE TO START THE QUIZ</h1>

            <div class="questions">
            <h2 class="topic"></h2>
            <h6 class="quest"></h6>
            <p class ="option" id="optionA"></p>
            <p class ="option" id="optionB"></p>
            <p class ="option" id="optionC"></p>
            <p class ="option" id="optionD"></p>
            <p class="nextbutton">NEXT></p>
            </div>
```